# What does "flush to the top" mean?

Tags: meaning

"Place your hand around the neck of the bottle, so that your hand is flush to the top". From [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Blow-the-Bottom-out-of-a-Bottle).

Comment: *Flush **with** something* is [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flush+with+the+edge%2C+flush+to+the+edge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: It’s like the typesetting directive to *flush left* or to *flush right*. It means to align.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "even with the top."  In other words, imagine your hand and the bottle pressed against the underside of a table.  If your hand is *flush with the top*, then both the top of your hand and the top of the bottle would be touching the undersurface with a relatively equal amount of pressure.

My online dictionary lists one definition of *flush* as "completely level or even with another surface."